# IndProp test_nostutter_4

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

The authors of the book have provided proofs for some unit tests for nostutter exercise. Unfortunately, they didn't provide explanations how they work. I was able to understand all the proofs but one:

```
Inductive nostutter {X:Type} : list X -> Prop :=
| ns_nil : nostutter []
| ns_one : forall (x : X), nostutter [x]
| ns_cons: forall (x : X) (h : X) (t : list X), nostutter (h::t) -> x <> h -> nostutter (x::h::t).

Example test_nostutter_4:      not (nostutter [3;1;1;4]).
Proof.
  intro.
  repeat match goal with
    h: nostutter _ |- _ => inversion h; clear h; subst
         end.
  contradiction.
Qed.
```

After intro we have the following:

```
1 subgoal (ID 454)

H : nostutter [3; 1; 1; 4]
============================
False
```

When I remove `repeat` and run match once, I get this:

```
1 subgoal (ID 519)

H2 : nostutter [1; 1; 4]
H4 : 3 <> 1
============================
False
```

So it tries to recursively find, where the list in H2 doesn't match any of nostutter constructors.

Can somebody explain me, how does this match work step by step? What is `goal` variable and `|-` symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first prove this in hard way.

```
Example test_nostutter_4:      not (nostutter [3;1;1;4]).
Proof.
  intro.
  (* You can think of this inversion H as 
     destructing nostutter [3; 1; 1; 4] into 
     ns_cons 3 1 [1; 4] (Trm : nostutter [1 :: 1 :: 4]) (Prf : 3 <> 1) *)
  inversion H.
  (* Let's invert Trm again. The process is same and I am leaving it for you to figure out*)
  inversion H2.
  (* At this point, you can easily that H9 say that 1 <> 1 which is off-course a false 
     assumption*)
  unfold not in H9.
  specialize (H9 eq_refl).
  Print False. (* False is inductive data type with no constructor*)
  inversion H9.
Qed.
```

As you can see that my proof has a lot of repetition, and we can easily automate them. Coq has tactic language called Ltac to combine tactics [1]. In your proof, the goal is

```
1 subgoal (ID 454)

H : nostutter [3; 1; 1; 4]
============================
False
```

and "match goal with" is pattern matching on goal. Everything at top of line (======) is assumption and below is the thing we need to prove. Rather than using line (======) to separate assumption with goal, Ltac uses turnstile (Assumption |- Goal [2]). I hope I am clear enough, but let me know if something is not clear.

[1] https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.match-goal

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)

Comment: Can you give a simple example of `match goal with` construction, explaining how it works?

Comment: As far as I understand: "h: nostutter _ |- _ =>" means: if one of hypothesis matches constructor `nostutter something` and goal matches something do the actions after `=>`. Correct? Why do they check only nostutter constructor with 1 argument, while we need a constructor with 3 arguments?

Comment: @user4035  You are almost right in first observation except nonstutter in not a constructor (constructor nostutter something), but it's family of types which takes list X to return a Prop.  They are checking on term of type nonstutter _ . "h: nostutter _ |- _ =>" matches a hypothesis h : nostutter _  or term h of type nostutter _  and it does not care what is on the right hand side of turnstile. Once it has found a match then it  invert the term h, followed by clearing from context and substituting all values "inversion h; clear h; subst" .

Comment: What do `Trm` and `Prf` shortcuts stand for?

Comment: @user4035 Basically, they are just variables like H0, H1, x but I named it Trm and Prf for make it explicit about term and proof, but you can safely ignore it.