# Understanding specialize tactic

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, logical-foundations

Trying to comprehend the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773900/789186) of @keep_learning I walked through this code step by step:

```
Inductive nostutter {X:Type} : list X -> Prop :=
| ns_nil : nostutter []
| ns_one : forall (x : X), nostutter [x]
| ns_cons: forall (x : X) (h : X) (t : list X), nostutter (h::t) -> x <> h -> nostutter (x::h::t).

Example test_nostutter_4: not (nostutter [3;1;1;4]).
Proof.
  intro.
  inversion_clear H.
  inversion_clear H0.
  unfold not in H2.
  (* We are here *)
  specialize (H2 eq_refl).
  apply H2.
Qed.
```

Here is what we have before excuting specialize

```
H1 : 3 <> 1
H : nostutter [1; 4]
H2 : 1 = 1 -> False
============================
False
```

Here is eq Prop whose constructor `eq_refl` is used in specialize:

```
Inductive eq (A:Type) (x:A) : A -> Prop :=
    eq_refl : x = x :>A

where "x = y :> A" := (@eq A x y) : type_scope.
```

I can't explain, how this command works:

```
specialize (H2 eq_refl).
```

I read about specialize in reference manual, but the explanation there is too broad. As far as I understand it sees that "1 = 1" expression in H2 satisfies `eq_refl` constructor and therefore eq proposition is True. Then it simplifies the expression:

```
True -> False => False
```

And we get

```
H1 : 3 <> 1
H : nostutter [1; 4]
H2 : False
============================
False
```

Can somebody provide me a minimal example with explanation of what is `specialize` doing, so I could freely use it?

**Update**

Trying to imitate how specialize works using apply I did the following:

```
Example specialize {A B: Type} (H: A -> B) (a: A): B.
Proof.
  apply H in a.
```

This gives:

```
A : Type
B : Type
H : A -> B
a : B
============================
B
```

Almost the same as `specialize`, only different hypothesis name.

In test_nostutter_4 theorem I tried this and it worked:

```
remember (@eq_refl nat 1) as Heq.
apply H2 in Heq as H3.
```

It gives us:

```
H1 : 3 <> 1
H : nostutter [1; 4]
H2 : 1 = 1 -> False
Heq : 1 = 1
H3 : False
HeqHeq : Heq = eq_refl
============================
False
```

This one was more complex, we had to introduce a new hypothesis Heq. But we got what we need - H3 at the end.

Does specialize internally use something like remember? Or is it possible to solve it with apply but without remember?

Comment: As a side note, `eq_refl` is not only a constructor, but it can also represent a concrete value (because it has an *implicit argument*). `H2 eq_refl` is the same as `H2 (@eq_refl 1)`.

Comment: @Bubbler Not `(@eq_refl 1)` but `(@eq_refl nat 1)`. `Check (@eq_refl nat 1).` gives "eq_refl     : 1 = 1" so this returns an object of eq Prop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`specialize`, in its simplest form, simply replaces a given hypothesis with that hypothesis applied to some other term.

In this proof,

```
Example specialize {A B: Type} (H: A -> B) (a: A): B.
Proof.
  specialize (H a).
  exact H.
Qed.
```

we initially have the hypothesis `H: A -> B`. When we call `specialize (H a)`, we apply `H` to `a` (apply as in function application). This gives us something of type `B`. `specialize` then gets rid of the old `H` for us and replaces it with the result of the application. It gives the new hypothesis the same name: `H`.

In your case, we have `H2: 1 = 1 -> False`, which is a function from the type `1 = 1` to the type `False`. That means that `H2` applied to `eq_refl` is of type `False`, i.e. `H2 eq_refl: False`. When we use the tactic `specialize (H2 eq_refl).`, the old `H2` is cleared and replaced by a new term (`H2 eq_refl`) whose type is `False`. It keeps the old name `H2`, though.

`specialize` is useful when you're sure that you're only going to use a hypothesis once, since it automatically gets rid of the old hypothesis. One disadvantage is that the old name may not fit the meaning of the new hypothesis. However, in your case and in my example, `H` is a generic enough name that it works either way.

---

To your update...

`specialize` is a core tactic defined directly in the ltac plugin. It doesn't use any other tactic internally, since it *is* its internals.

If you want to keep a hypothesis, you can use the `as` modifier, which works for both `specialize` and `apply`. In the proof

```
Example specialize {A B: Type} (H: A -> B) (a: A): B.
Proof.
```

if you do `specialize (H a) as H0.`, instead of clearing `H`, it'll introduce a new hypothesis `H0: B`. `apply H in a as H0.` has the same effect.

Comment: I updated the question: tried to imitate `specialize` with apply. Another subquestion has arisen about remember. Is it the only way to solve this using apply? Please, look.

Comment: "If you want to keep a hypothesis" - I wanted to imitate how specialize works, using the tactics that I already know.

Comment: @Scappella The "as" statement is not working here, returns an error. "Syntax error: '.' or '...' expected after [tactic:tactic] (in [proof_mode:subgoal_command])."